# Standard formation enthalpy or entropy. What is temperature is standard conditions?

Tags: enthalpy

I am reading Atkins's Physical Chemistry.
In section Thermochemistry, in subsection 2.7 Standard enthalpy changes
It states that

> As implied by the examples, standard enthalpies may be reported for any temperature.
> However, the conventional temperature for reporting thermodynamic data is
> 298.15 K (corresponding to 25.00°C). Unless otherwise mentioned, all thermodynamic
> data in this text will refer to this conventional temperature.

I found many examples in the book that give data at 298 K. It is omitting the decimals or is it a different criterion?
If you check wikipedia page of Standard enthalpy of formation, both numbers are used? Are there many criteria?